# VB.Net Forms - MDI forms not locating correctly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mdi

I have a problem with MDI forms and their location.  I have a container form within which I open several child forms.  Also note that in the container form I have a ToolStrip at the top and it is also docked to the top.  In each of the child forms I have set the following properties.  I have set them at design time as well but it wasn't working for some reason so I put them in the form_load event as well.

```
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
Me.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
ReSizeAndArrange(Me.Width, Me.Height, False)
```

The function `ReSizeAndArrange` is called on `form_load` and `form_layout` events.  The problem I am having is that the child forms do not fill the remaining space correctly or for that matter the entire parent form.  When I step through, here are the coordinates I am getting for the child form.

```
frmContainer.Size   {Width = 972 Height = 972}  System.Drawing.Size
me.Size     {Width = 968 Height = 901}  System.Drawing.Size
frmContainer.ToolStripMain.Size {Width = 954 Height = 67}   System.Drawing.Size
frmContainer.Location   {X = 90 Y = 22} System.Drawing.Point
me.Location     {X = -9 Y = -36}    System.Drawing.Point
```

Shouldn't the `Me.Location` be `0,0`? The numbers add up on the sizes I think. The 4 pixel difference can perhaps be explained by the border, however, the location is unexplained.  Can anyone decipher this?

Comment: The code is not important, because I am trapping the above values in the first line of that function.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the problem myself simply by setting the location of the form to (0,0).  It still doesn't answer the question, but it is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It's because 0, 0 doesn't put constraints on the form size/layout. It allows it to decide. Any value you put in there forces the form to conform to YOUR specs. 0, 0 isn't a work around, it's the "you decide this yourself form" way of doing it.

Comment: I apologize, but I did not understand your explanation.  Could you please elaborate?